# DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK is On in my table.But still temporal table inserts another row for same data update .How can I restrict in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, audit, temporal-tables

DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK  is On in my table. I'm trying to check data consistency for audit purpose.When I update same value in the main table, the temporal table keeps history of the same row, which causes difficult to track the version changes.I'm using MSSQL server.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no such thing as "DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK" standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Then just don't _update same value_ - that is flawed application / programming logic. You should NEVER update a row when there is no actual change to the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the function of DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK option. It's used to check if time ranges definded by system_start_time_column_name and system_end_time_column_name columns in PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME do not overlap in base and historical table when you enable the link between the base and historical table ( this done when you execute CREATE/ALTER TABLE command).

If you need data deduplication in historical table you have to implement it yourself. It can be a maintenance task which disable the link, remove duplicates, update the time range columns correctely and enable link between base and historical table back.